# Example of using require() to use OpenSeadragon

Tags: node.js, openseadragon

I'm an OpenSeadragon newb, and I would prefer to use npm to install it rather than depend on a downloaded version.

I'm having a little trouble with the syntax, and (so far) no amount of Googling has come up with an example.  I assume it would look something like this:

var viewer = require('openseadragon');

But then, in particular, how would the prefixURL option be set?

Are there examples out there I haven't found?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, the current version of OpenSeadragon (2.1.0) published on npm does not support require yet.
It will be available with the next release and should be used like this:

```
var openseadragon = require('openseadragon');
var viewer = openseadragon({
  prefixUrl: 'url',
  ...
});
```

In the mean time, you will have to include OSD manually:

```
<script src="node_modules/openseadragon/build/openseadragon/openseadragon.js"></script>
```

And create an instance like this:

```
var viewer = OpenSeadragon({
  prefixUrl: 'url',
  ...
});
```

Comment: Will the images path still have to poke deep  into the modules directory space?

Comment: Good point. I think so and I don't know if there is anyway we can improve that. It looks like this webpack plugin could help: https://github.com/webpack/file-loader

Comment: I opened an issue about that: https://github.com/openseadragon/openseadragon/issues/792

Comment: uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuugh javascript these days. I just added packages to my meteor app to let me use npm packages so I could require openseadragon and now I can't require openseadragon because meteor doesn't let you do script src and urrrrgh the fatigue